# "The method selectByValue(String) undefined for the type WebElement" in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can you please some one help me to finish this..

I want to write selenium code for drop down. when I'm trying to use below syntax. Im getting this error in eclipse "The method selectByValue(String) undefined for the type WebElement".

I'm using below syntax:

```
ele.selectByIndex(5);
ele.selectByValue("3");
ele.selectByVisibleText(Feb);
```

Thanks in advance...

I have updated after I found the solution.
I have written the code like this for others can use. it's working fine for me.

```
public void selectCreditCardType(WebElement selectCreditCardType) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Select Card");
    browser.selectByText(selectCreditCardType, "Visa Card");
    browser.Wait(10);
}
```

Comment: probably your element `ele` don't have an `value` Attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `selectByVisibleText();` method takes argument as String and you are passing value as webelement that's why it showing error

Just change your argument type to String (enclose in `"`) and try

```
ele.selectByVisibleText("Feb");
```

**Updated :**

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//select[@name='CTYPE']")
    private WebElement selectCreditCard;
    public void selectCreditCardType() throws Exception 
    {
    logger.info("Select Card");
    Select select = new Select(selectCreditCard);
    select.selectByIndex(2); 
    }
```

Comment: @suresh kumar  Can you replace these `Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='CTYPE']"))); 
select.selectByIndex(2);` and let us know any error you faced

Comment: Sorry for the delay... plz dont mind.. purchaseInsurance.selectBankBranch(); .. When Im calling this in test page.. showing error "multiple marks" in Eclipse

Comment: I want to select two dropdowns for date i.e. MM YYYY

Comment: Then you have to locate both dropdown separate e.g.     `Select dd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='date']"‌​)));
    dd.selectByIndex(2);`  and  `Select yy = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='year']"‌​)));
    yy.selectByIndex(2);` like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139564/discussion-between-suresh-kumar-and-narendra-rajput).

Answer (score 1):

Carefully look at the error message.

> "The method selectByValue(String) undefined for the type WebElement"

It's saying that you are doing the equivalent of `WebElement.selectByValue()` which is not defined. `.selectByValue()` is defined for a `Select`. You didn't post all the relevant code to your example but you likely have code like

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(locator);
ele.selectByIndex(5);
```

which means that `ele` is of `WebElement` type. You are trying to set a value in a `SELECT` element so you would want to use the `Select` class. You can do this like

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(locator);
Select select = new Select(ele);
select.selectByIndex(5);
```

You should spend some time reviewing the [Selenium docs for Java](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/), especially the [`Select`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... 
Sorry to say this.. still facing same issue. Im lit bit confusion. can you plz tell me for below code..


@FindBy(xpath = "//select[@name='CTYPE']")
private WebElement slctCreditCardType;


public void selectCreditCardType() throws Exception {
 logger.info("Select Card");
 Select select = new Select(slctCreditCardType);
 select.selectByIndex(2);
  }

Comment: Please post the code in your question so everyone can see it, it can be properly formatted, and post the full error message.